# Adding badge to TabbedPage ToolBarItems from shared code

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

How can I add a badge to one of TabbedPage ToolBarItems? I create all my pages and tabs in shared code (forms) and I see no way of doing it there (I can just set name, icon). Probably I'll have to do it specifically for each platform (let's say iOS is enough), but in a way that I can control badge value from shared code- I need the badge to have value of count of list items (list is inside that tab), so I'll need to update it as the list is changing.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Are you wanting an icon to be displayed within each tab for the different pages contained within the `TabbedPage`? So instead of the tabs saying Page1 | Page 2 | Page 3, it would have icon 1 | icon 2 | icon 3? If so that is definitely possible without custom renderers.

Answer (score 0):

Only things that exists on both iOS and Android platforms are implemented in Xamarin.Forms. And it seems like there are no badges out of the box for Android.
But you still can implement a custom renderer for your TabBarItem which will use the iOS badge and some Android library for this.